# Am I storing this data to iCloud properly?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, icloud

So I ran into this tutorial, and followed it.  I am just using it to store couple of boolenas.

Anyway I dont exactly understand how this script manages to store to iCloud since I have done nothing related to iCloud except simply allow it under capabilities.  I have also tested it in couple scenarios and haven't had any issues.  Can you think of times where this might be an issue?

http://nicemohawk.com/blog/2015/08/storing-key-value-data-in-icloud-with-swift/

If you are willing to look over my code to make sure I did it right please do!  What is going on is their are six keys that are "HASpayedFOR1", "HASpayedFOR2" etc etc.  And these store a bool on wether this character has been unlocked yet.  Their are two storage spaces.

NSUserDefaults
And the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore

NSUserDefaults is what usually stores everything and all the game values, NSUmbiquitousKeyValueStore is holding all the stuff I want on the "cloud".  I have two main functions one that restores from the cloud, and another that saves to it.  These are called when appropriate. Note that none of the functions allow it to go backwards.  So for instance the restore code will only set things to true, and the save code will only set things to true.

Can you see any sort of crashing that could happen due to an unforeseen network error?

```
var iCloudKeyStore: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore? = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore()

    func c_reportCloud()
    {
        if let iCloudKeyStore2 = iCloudKeyStore
        {
            for var i = 0; i < 7; i++
            {
                print("Icloud for " + String(i) + "  :")
                println(iCloudKeyStore2.boolForKey("HASpayedFOR" + String(i)))

            }
        }
    }



    func c_restoreCharecters()
    {
        iCloudKeyStore?.synchronize()
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


        var current:[Bool] = []

        for var i = 0; i < 7; i++
        {
            current.append(defaults.boolForKey("HASpayedFOR" + String(i)))
        }

        var cloud:[Bool] = []

        if let iCloudKeyStore2 = iCloudKeyStore
        {
            for var i = 0; i < 7; i++
            {

                cloud.append(iCloudKeyStore2.boolForKey("HASpayedFOR" + String(i)))
            }
        }
        var meme:[Bool] = []
        for var i = 0; i < 7; i++
        {
            //If we dont have it and the cloud does then get it from the cloud!
            if (current[i] == false)
            {
                if (cloud[i] == true)
                {
                    meme.append(true)
                    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "HASpayedFOR" + String(i))
                }
                else
                {
                    meme.append(false)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                meme.append(false)
            }
        }


        //Force the opening of them


        if let it = spriteKit.scene as? Menu
        {

            it.open(meme)

        }



       // iCloudKeyStore?.setString(textField.text, forKey: iCloudTextKey)



        /*for var i = 0; i < 7; i++
        {
            print("Has unlocked charecter: " + String(i))
            println(defaults.boolForKey("HASpayedFOR" + String(i)))
        }*/
    }


    func c_savePlayers()
    {
        iCloudKeyStore?.synchronize()
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


        var current:[Bool] = []

        for var i = 0; i < 7; i++
        {
            current.append(defaults.boolForKey("HASpayedFOR" + String(i)))
        }

        var cloud:[Bool] = []

        if let iCloudKeyStore2 = iCloudKeyStore
        {
            for var i = 0; i < 7; i++
            {

                cloud.append(iCloudKeyStore2.boolForKey("HASpayedFOR" + String(i)))
            }
        }


        if let iCloudKeyStore2 = iCloudKeyStore
        {
            for var i = 0; i < 7; i++
            {
                //If we have something the cloud doesnt
                if (current[i] == true)
                {
                    if (cloud[i] == false)
                    {
                        iCloudKeyStore2.setBool(true, forKey: "HASpayedFOR" + String(i))
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        iCloudKeyStore?.synchronize()
    }
```

Thanks much!